# Prove/Refute that $L=\{w\$x^R \ |\ x\ is\ a\ substring\ of\ w\}$ is a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I was solving some exercises about CFL from past years' homework and faced this question.

***Question:*** Given the language $L=\{w \# x^R \ | \ x\ is\ a\ substring\ of\ w\}$, prove/refute if it's regular language. If you proved it's regular then provide NFA and a regular expression that describes it. Otherwise, provide CFG and PDA for it.

***My Answer:*** I think that the language is not regular but couldn't prove it so I provided CFG and PDA for it.

If anyone can tell whether the language is regular or not and therefore provide proof for that I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $L$ is regular and let $p$ be its pumping length. Consider the word $a^p\#a^p \in L$. By the pumping lemma there is some $1 \le k \le p$ such that $a^{p-k}a^{ki}\#a^p \in L$ for all choices of a non-negative integer $i$. Choosing $i=0$ yields $a^{p-k}\#a^p \in L$, which is a contradiction since $(a^p)^R = a^p$ is not a substring of $a^{p-k}$.

Comment: Oh, I really tried to use the pumping lemma but forgot about that $i$ could be $0$. Thanks a lot.